# How do I redirect the output of Trace.WriteLine to Enterprise Library Logging block?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, enterprise-library-5

I have legacy code that is making use of `Trace.WriteLine` everywhere.

I decided to use Microsoft Enterprise Library to log the traces. So I can decide to write to a file, send an email, log to the database o create my own custom listener.

How do I redirect the output of `Trace.WriteLine` to Enterprise Library Logging block?

UPDATE:
I can use code. But what type of I need to pass to Trace.Listeners.Add?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static method `Trace.Listeners.Add`.